# Add bullet styling to dd element

Tags: css, xhtml

I am using `dl`, `dt` and `dd` tags in one of my projects. I want to show a bullet before `dd`. How can I make my `dd`s into a bullet list using CSS?

Comment: Thanks guys display: list-item did the magic

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Easiest way is to change the properties on your `<dd>`

```
dd {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    }
```

Works in every browser.

See this article: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: May also need to play with the margin/padding.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the style attribute in the "dd" tag, or move that to a "style"
section as a class or id. Since the dl is a list type you do not need the
"display: list-item;" I think, might also be wrong. Anyways This might be used.
Instead of the disc, you might use other types (look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style-type.asp)...

```
<html>
  <body>
    <dl>
      <dt>Term</dt>
      <dd style="display: list-item;">Term description</dd>
    </dl>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: inline styles are bad practice ... use the stylesheet ... that's what it's for!

Answer (score 0):

Use a background-image.

Or try:

```
dd
{
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

No idea if it will work though.

Answer (score 0):

tested it in firefox and just adding the style display:list-item should do the trick