# css html definition list question

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Styling the DD tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721116/styling-the-dd-tag)

Is it possible to HAVE a bullet in front of a `<dd>` tag just like `<li>` i cannot use `<li>` because i need to validate and `<dl><dt>`and `<dd>` is just fine

Comment: In what situation is <ul> invalid but <dl> is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it with a background image.

```
dt { background: transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat; padding-left: 20px; }
```

**EDIT:** added padding-left.

Comment: Note:  you will obviously want this in combination with left padding.

Answer (score 0):

By default a definition list doesn't have bullets. But you can use an image like jessegavin suggested. Remember about margins, paddings and .png problems with IE6 when you use a solution like this.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be possible to play around with CSS like this?

```
dt:before {
  content: "•";
  position: ...;
  margin: ...;
}
```

This is not nice, but... well, using a definition list element if you do not actually want a definition list to be shown is ugly anyway.