# How can I get an HTML definition list to respect with list-style-type styling rules?

Tags: css

So I'm marking up a client's web design. The page is an FAQs page, in which each FAQ section has a list of questions and answers. The most appropriate, semantic markup for this scenario is the html definition list.

The client's mockup also shows numbers beside each question/answer pair, such as an ordered list would have.

So naturally I thought I would just mark up the content with the `<dl>` element, and use CSS to add `list-style-type: decimal`. However, this is completely ignored.

Is it because the `<dl>` element cannot accept list-styling? That seems terribly backwards, as it is, after all, a list element!

Or am I doing something wrong with my markup?

Here's an example of my code CSS and HTML:

```css
dl { list-style: decimal; }
```

```html
<dl class="some-list">

  <dt><strong>Q</strong>: How Do I Do Some Thing?</dt>
  <dd><p><strong>A:</strong> You just do it, okay? Want a longer explanation? Try this: You just do it, okay? Want a longer explanation? Try this: You just do it, okay? Want a longer explanation? Try this: You just do it, okay? Want a longer explanation? Try this:</p>
  </dd>

  <dt><strong>Q</strong>: How Do I Do Some Other Thing?</dt>
  <dd><p><strong>A:</strong> You just do it, okay? Want a longer explanation? Try this: You just do it, okay? Want a longer explanation? Try this: You just do it, okay? Want a longer explanation? Try this: You just do it, okay? Want a longer explanation? Try this:</p>
  </dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721116/add-bullet-styling-to-dd-element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-type):

> The list-style-type CSS property specifies appearance of a list item
>   element. As it is the only one who defaults to display:list-item, this
>   is usually a <li> element, but can be any element with this display
>   value.

You can apply `display:list-item` to your `dt` element in CSS, and then also apply a `list-style-type` option to it as well.

```css
dt.wanna-be-list {
  display:list-item;
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uvrYd/) :

```
<html>

<dl class="faq">
    <dt>How much wood would a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck wood?</dt>
    <dd>1,000,000</dd>
    <dt>What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?</dt>
    <dd>What do you mean? An African or European swallow?</dd>
    <dt>Why did the chicken cross the road?</dt>
    <dd>To get to the other side</dd>
</dl>

<css>

.faq {
    counter-reset: my-badass-counter;
}
.faq dd {
    margin: 0 0 50px;
}
.faq dt:before {
    content: counter(my-badass-counter, decimal);
    counter-increment: my-badass-counter;
    font: bold 50px/1 Sans-Serif;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.faq dt, .faq dd {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.faq dt {
    font: bold 16px Georgia;
    padding: 4px 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

From [this explanation](http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/) you can see it working [in this example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/NumberedFAQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ol(ordered list) instead, the style should work(ul for unordered).

Comment: The OP is not using a `<ul>`.

Comment: Thanks, but the `<dl>` element most accurately & semantically describes the content, so I'm not looking for a solution that involves changing the markup. I'm looking for a solution for this with CSS.

Comment: @JoelGlovier you can always use your(insert language here) and add in front of each line the number of a id(from database, ordened by this id)